# How to decode an array?

Tags: php

I have this PHP array

```
$gender = array (
    0  => array('Male','m.gif'),
    1  => array('Female','f.gif'),
    2  => array('Other','o.gif'),
);
```

And this ODBC

```
$DB = $core_db->Execute("SELECT ID, Name, Age, Location, Gender FROM Profiles 
ORDER BY Name");
```

I want to use `echo' . decode_gender($DB->fields[4], '2') . ';` But I don't know how to **make** this decode function to connect that `$DB->fields[4]` is the same Gender from the array `$gender` in order to use it.

Comment: Show your `decode_gender()` function, Also i noticed that you should produce error, since `echo' . decode_gender($DB->fields[4], '2') . ';` should be `echo decode_gender($DB->fields[4], '2');`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I don't have this function I want to make it, but I don't know how..

Comment: What is the point of the `'2'` parameter to the function?

Comment: @Nick to use *.gif part of the array

Comment: Is the `Gender` field in the database a string e.g. `Male` or a number e.g. `0`?

Comment: @Nick 0,1,2 the same as the array

Comment: Hi there, could you add the extra information to your question as an edit rather than/as well as putting it into comments? This adds all the extra detail in the one place that everyone looks at first.

Comment: @Michelle, you are right, this questions is answered, so I'll do my best next time to give max possible details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do what you want. It takes the `Gender` value from the table lookup to index into the `$genders` array, and the second parameter to decide which value from the lookup array to return. Note that since you've said you want a value of 2 to return the second value in the array, you have to subtract one from the `$idx` value:

```
function decode_gender($gender, $idx) {
    $genders = array (
        0  => array('Male','m.gif'),
        1  => array('Female','f.gif'),
        2  => array('Other','o.gif'),
    );
    return $genders[$gender][$idx-1];
}

echo decode_gender(2, 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo decode_gender(1, 1) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
o.gif
Female
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Gf3Pk)

Comment: I'm sorry can you help with this also? calling-if-in-loop << post

Comment: @IsaacSabir use a function, something like this: https://3v4l.org/EHmuf

Comment: I dunno how to thank you, really thank you is not enough.

Comment: the function is working perfectly but it gives me the same value in all columns (repeating as first row result) how to make it change to next value in the loop ?

Comment: You should be using something like `$AgeTitle = user_title($DB->fields[2])` in your `while` loop

Comment: @IsaacSabir I can't see why it would do that. I would suggest updating that question with your current code, it will be easier to debug if you can see all the code